# Allow any IPs to private_url but only allow whitelisted IPs to public_url in nginx

Tags: nginx, whitelist

I have a Java Spring app on WebSphere behind nginx.
I have
`my_website.com/private_url`
`my_website.com/public_url`
Currently both addresses are accessible from any IP. What is the correct way to tell nginx to only accept requests to `my_website.com/private_url` from list of whitelisted subnets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deny access to everybody except certain addresses to a specific directory or request add this location block

```
location ^~ /private_url {
  allow x.x.x.x/32;
  allow x.y.x.x/16; 
  deny all;
}
```

The rules are checked in sequence from top to bottom until the first match is found.

You should add this in nginx.conf, but you don't want editing this file every time you want to add new ip. So instead write all ip addresses in a whitelist.conf in nginx home directory and include this file in location block.

**whitelist.conf**

```
allow x.x.x.x/32;
allow x.y.x.x/16;
```

**nginx.conf**

```
location ^~ /private_url {
  include whitelist.conf; 
  deny all;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.